# Shake Gesture isn't working in iPhone 4, Don't know why...?

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iPhone app which uses Shake Gesture to rotate the wheel of picker view. I am using IOS 3.2 as base sdk. I have a iPhone 3GS which is updated with IOS 4.0, when I execute my App in this 3GS phone it is working properly with Shake Gesture. but when I run it in iPhone 4 the Shake Gesture doesn't respond. I am not getting the reason of it, if anybody is having the Solotion please help me out... Below i am providing a code part which i hv used to handle Shake Gesture....

```
#define kRowMultiplier          20
#define kAccelerationThreshold      2.2
#define kUpdateInterval         (1.0f/10.0f)



(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate: UIAcceleration*)acceleration{

    if (fabsf(acceleration.x) > kAccelerationThreshold || fabsf(acceleration.y) > kAccelerationThreshold || fabsf(acceleration.z) > kAccelerationThreshold) {       
        [progressView startAnimating];

        if (! isSpinning)
        {       
            if(!btnRegion.selected && !btnFlavor.selected && !btnPrice.selected)
            {
                // Need to have it stop blurring a fraction of a second before it stops spinning so that the final appearance is not blurred.
                [self stopBlurring];
                wheelingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(shufflePickerView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            }
            else 
            {
                [self shufflePickerView];
                [self performSelector:@selector(stopBlurring) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.7];
            }
        }
        isSpinning = YES;       
    }   

}
```

is sumthing wrong in code... Can I test it by Simulator on IOS 4.0 or i need to hv a iPhone 4 only...?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Hugo for the Solution, But i got another way to do it before many days n I guess its quite easy...

we can do it by this way...

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

     if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) 
    {
              //Put your code here what you want to do on a shake...
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. 
My code tested on an iPhone 3G works fine, on an iPhone 4 it doesn't work. Both running on iOS 4.2.1

UPDATE: Used this method and it works great:
http://www.softvelopment.com/index.php/blogs/2010/03/19/3-adding-shake-recongnition-to-cocos2d-iphone-library-

Comment: Thanks Hugo for the Solution, But i got another way to do it before many days n I guess its quite easy...